# SlimDX Assembly Reference

Tags: visual-studio, directx, slimdx, assembly-reference-path

I've installed SlimDX but the assembly reference does not come up as a choice in Visual Studio, and I cannot for the life of me find out where SlimDX has installed itself! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank,

Mikey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure you installed the SlimDX Developer SDK, not runtime redistributable.

If you've done that, by default, it will be installed into `Program Files\SlimDX SDK (release date)\Bin\x86`  (and x64, depending on the platform).